# What is the most efficient way to parse the specific segments of a URL path?

Tags: php

Say my url is **www.example.com/usa/california/redding/**

What is the most efficient way to return the following:

```
$urls = array ( 0 => '/usa/', 1 => '/usa/california/', 2 => '/usa/california/redding/' );
```

The actual URL will be unknown and the length / number of segments will be unknown.

Comment: I don't know why you want *that*, but [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) is generally a useful tool for decomposing URLs in a sane way...

Comment: Thank you. That returns the path, which I already know.

Comment: Ok, in which case your question should really be "how to parse a *path*" ;)

Comment: Good call. My question was a bit malformed as it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way to do this would be to loop over the string, looking each consecutive / character and then pushing them onto an array as you go.  This algorithm will be O(n) assuming string concatenation is also O(n).

```
$url = "www.example.com/usa/california/redding/";
$next = "";
$urls = array();
// we use the strpos function to get position of the first /
// this let's us ignore the host part of the url
$start = strpos($url, "/");
// just in case PHP uses C strings or something (doubtful)
$length = strlen($url);

// loop over the string, taking one character at a time
for ($i = $start; $i < $length; $i++) {
  // append the character to our temp string
  $next .= $url[$i];
  // skip the first slash, but after that push the value of
  // next onto the array every time we see a slash
  if ($i > $start && $url[$i] == "/") {
    array_push($urls, $next);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, it is a gorgeous solution and your comments made things very clear and educational.

Answer (score 1):

Not too elegant, but this gets the job done:

```
<?php
$link = 'www.example.com/usa/california/redding/';
$parts = explode('/',$link);

$results = array();
for ($i = 1; $i < count($parts) - 1; $i++) {
    $results[] = '/'.implode('/', array_slice($parts, 1,$i)).'/';
}
print_r($results);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the `regular expression` is the first though came to me, but i know it might not be `efficient`:

```
    $str = 'www.example.com/usa/california/redding/';
    $patten = '/(((\/.[0-9A-Za-z]+\/).[0-9A-Za-z]+\/).[0-9A-Za-z]+\/)/';
    $ret = preg_match($patten, $str, $matches);
    var_export($matches);
```

the output will be:

```
 array (
   0 => '/usa/california/redding/',
   1 => '/usa/california/redding/',
   2 => '/usa/california/',
   3 => '/usa/',
 )
```

first is the whole match, the remain 3 is the capture.

Comment: Thank you. I think your solution is elegant but it wont scale to a url with more or less than 3 segments.

Comment: Yes, `regular expression` is little `scalable`. :)